# Gazebo SDF file, Defining Motor & Prop parameters like MaxRotVel, RotorDragCoefficient etc

Tags: gazebo, motor, sdf, px4

I am new to Gazebo SDF file generation and I am facing problems in defining motor parameters. Can anyone give an understanding (also where to get it). Iris is an example which is already there as a template. I was editing it to suit dimensions to my drone "H-Hex". I am stuck at defining motor parameters. Following are parameters which I need to give in Gazebo SDF file which i was unable to find. I also wrote my understanding next to it.

1. Time Constant Up - (Is it similar to hardware delay =>time taken to get the physical effect(eg: RPM change) after command is given by controller)
2. Time constant down - ((Is it similar to hardware delay =>time taken to get the physical effect(eg: RPM change) after command is given by controller)
3. Max Rotational Velocity (is it in rad/s, which is not matching with predefined motors)
4. Motor Constant - (was able to find value from below links but not matching with predefined motors of iris or typhoon drones)
5. Moment Constant - (was able to find value from below links but not matching with predefined motors of iris or typhoon drones)
6. Rotor Drag Coefficient - (Is it blades' drag coefficient at max RPM)
7. Rolling moment Coefficient - (did not understand at all . is it rolling moment coefficient about rotor blade hinge line(at certain RPM) caused by aerodynamic force on blade at that particular RPM?)

I also referred to

https://github.com/PX4/PX4-SITL_gazebo-classic/issues/110

https://github.com/PX4/PX4-SITL_gazebo-classic/issues/995

https://github.com/mvernacc/gazebo_motor_model_docs/blob/master/notes.pdf

Thanks in Advance

Aditya

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
At least 8) is a totally different topic, please refer to some basic quadcopter articles. (the answer is yes)

Comment: Thanks. I will refer documents for 8) but all the remaining 7 i was able to get some values based on the references mentioned but those formulas dont match with the motor parameters mentoned in template "iris" or "typhoon"